# Drag and Drop realization

Tags: python

I am a music teacher and trying to teach my students with some hand-made program.

I had learned programming language in a elementary level, such as Python, Java, Pro-log etc.

I have a Open Lecture with parents of my students upcoming 12/12, so I want to make a simple lecture program.

Two Image Below is the U.I. which I want to realize.

[4/4beat_practing1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg308.png) 
[4/4beat practing2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE0kg.png)

First, I want to make an apple droppable to match the gray-colored field. I want (half-sized apple should be matched to half-sized grayfield, and same for the full-sized color.)

Second, I want to make notes are droppable so that they could be aligned on the bar. In this case, it the summation is not 4/4beat, I want to show Error.

In which way, I could make this program fast?

I think I can encode the elementary level of programing such as checking out whether the summation is 4/4beat or not, however, I don't know how to connect programmed codes being linked with those images and User interfaces yet.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you're asking for someone to provide the code for your desired UI, then this question is off-topic. You should try to make it yourself as best you can, then share any issues you get.

Comment: no, I want to make it by myself. After learning it, I want to share it with my co-workers, with other teachers.

Comment: At the moment, your question is probably too broad because you haven't shown what you've done so far, therefore there could be many answers that work for you. Which GUI toolkit do you want to use? Have you started to create what you can?

Comment: Which GUI Toolkit do you recommend? I think I don't have an appropriate knowledge which Toolkit I have to choose. please help me to narrow the question.

Comment: I think either @zenlc2000's suggestion or Kivy could be good choices. Have a look at some examples for each one and see which seems best for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Aurora! will figure out which would be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

For an application like that, I would suggest using [PyGame](http://pygame.org/hifi.html). I've seen beginning students with no programming skill at all make impressive games in only a few weeks with it.

Unfortunately, I'm not a game builder so I can't answer technical questions about PyGame. But I do know it has the sound and graphics libraries you need for your demonstration.

Comment: Thank you zenelc. will try PyGame.